# Laravel Triple Relationship

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, relationship, has-many-through

What is the correct way to make triple relationship in Laravel. I'm using the last version of Laravel.

I need to make Brand/Category/Product relationship.

My table like this :

```
Table brands = id - name - slug
Table categories = id - name - slug
Table brand_category = brand_id (foreign key) - category_id (foreign key)
Table products = id - name - slug - brand_id (foreign key) - category_id (foreign key)
```

Need to do correctly : Brands can have many Categories and vice versa. Also Brands and Categories have many products. Products belongs to Brands and Categories via foreign key. What is the best way to make relationship between them ? I posted here because double hasmany relationship sounds weird. Hasmanythrough seems good but i couldn't mind how to cover it to this relationship.

Models :

**Brand.php**

```
 class Brand extends Model
{
    // Table Name
    protected $table = 'brands';

    // Primary Key
    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    // Timestamps
    public $timestamps = true;

    /**
     * The category that belong to the brand.
     */
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }

    /**
     * Brand has many products.
     */
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

**Category.php**

```
 class Category extends Model
{
     // Table Name
    protected $table = 'categories';

    /**
     * The brand that belongs to the category.
    */
    public function brands()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Brand');
    }

    /**
     * The category has many products.
     */
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }

}
```

**Product.php**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    //Table Name
    protected $table = 'products';

    /**
     * The product that belongs to the brand.
    */
    public function brands()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Brand');
    }

     /**
     * The product that belongs to the category.
    */
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

Comment: You describe here 2 types of category, one for product and one for brand. Is that right or I've got you wrong? If it is the same, are you trying to keep only 1 foreign key in your product table (lets say category_id) and from that reach also to the other one (brand_id)?

Comment: @MyLibary Yeah 2 types of category but of course i should list products related to categories and categories related to brands. For example, `Apple/Phones/iphone-7` or site.com/phones/apple. I can reach these urls. I just wonder the correct relationship. Products table hold brand_id and category_id both but there is no more table for this relationship without brand_category table.

Comment: To be honest, it is achievable, but the flow seems odd to me. It is OK to have categories for brands which is different from the products categories (unless it is the same for you).

In real world product related to brand and category(es), so lets say Iphone 7 is associated with the "Phone" category and "Apple" brand.
The product URL would be HOSTNAME/category-name/product-name or just HOSTNAME/product-name but HOSTNAME/brand-name/category-name/product-name is just odd.

I just wonder if you were thinking about it?

Comment: Okay i got it. I just want to make HOSTNAME/product-name and HOSTNAME/category-name/product-name. So is this relationship correct for this ?

Comment: If so, all you need is having a relation one-to-many between product and brands (brands has many products) and many-to-many between products and categories (as I assume that product might be related to multiple categories).

Comment: @MyLibary I updated my comment, Products related to brands and categories. That's all i want to do. I just wonder if double hasmany situation is correct or not at this point ? I mean brand has many products and categories has many products relation is correct ?

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: @Plunch absolutely.